# Image cache clearing issue

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jquery to open popups. My popup content consist of image and text.

When I click pop1 I get my pop1 content. When I click pop2 for few seconds I see my pop1 content and then my pop2 loads. How can I fix this?

my popup code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

///////LINKS - POPUP//////// 
 $('#all').delegate('a.pop-lnk', 'click', function(){
  var page = $(this).attr('id');

  $('#popup').empty();

  $('#gr-out').css({ opacity: 0.7, 'width':$(document).width(),'height':$(document).height()}).show();
  $('#popup').css({'display': 'block'});
  $('#popup').load("../phpHandler.php?page="+ page);
 })

 $('body').delegate('.hide-it', 'click', function(){ 
  $('.hide-it').hide();
    })
});
```

my php that handles the links (phpHandler):

```
<?php
 $page = $_GET['page'];
 $pages = array('pop1',
                'pop2');

 if (!empty($page)) {
  if(in_array($page,$pages)){
   $page .= '.php';
   require_once('../' . $page . '');
  }
  else require_once('../err.php');
 }
 else require_once('../err.php');
?>
```

Comment: `$('#popup').empty()` before you display it, so the previous content is cleared. Right now you're showing it BEFORE the new content is loaded, so whatever was in it before will still be there.

Comment: alternatively: `$('#popup').load(...).complete(this.show())` kind of thing would also work. don't display it until AFTER the new content's been fully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you first show the element containing the previously loaded pop1 content

```
$('#gr-out').css({ opacity: 0.7, 'width':$(document).width(),'height':$(document).height()}).show();
$('#popup').css({'display': 'block'});
```

and then you start to load the new content

```
$('#popup').load("../phpHandler.php?page="+ page);
```

It is not a caching but a timing issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Show the popup in a `.load` callback so that the html is loaded before you show it.

```
$('#popup').load("../phpHandler.php?page="+ page, function(){
    $('#popup').css({'display': 'block'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you hide your modal, clear out its contents.

```
$('body').delegate('.hide-it', 'click', function(){ 
        $('.hide-it').hide();
        $('#popup').empty();
    })
});
```